# The volume of black hole using Parikh's geometric definition

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, volume

It is mentioned in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0508108) (by Parikh) that the volume of stationary black holes can be computed through a geometric definition, which (I think) is not common in literature. The definition of volume in this method for a $D$-dimensional black hole spacetime is as

$$V = \frac{d}{{dt}}\left[ {\int_t^{t + dt} {dt'} \int {dr} \int {{d^{D - 2}}\vec x\sqrt { - {g_{(D)}}} } } \right],$$

where ${g_{(D)}}$ is the determinant of $D$-dimensional black hole metric (in this method, $g_{(D)}$ is used instead of $g_{(D-1)}$). For example, the volume of 4-D Schwarzschild black holes takes the form: $V = \frac{4}{3}\pi r_ + ^3$. For horizon with a planar symmetry, through a toroidal compactification of all the transverse directions on the horizon, the horizon area also becomes finite. I wonder to know what are the advantages and disadvantages of using this definition before starting computations or learning this subject in depth? For example, does it have applications in black hole thermodynamics? Has anyone here dealt with this definition of volume and its consequences before?

Let me explain why such a definition has been introduced: "The surface area (horizon area) is invariant and also well-defined for a $D$-dimensional black hole. However, the full $D$-dimensional volume of the black hole region is formally infinite. And, the volume intrinsic to a ($D-1$)-dimensional hypersurface depends on the choice of slicing. For these reasons, the above definition for volume has been invented which gives a slicing-invariant volume, as the author claimed." I would be grateful if you could clarify more on this. Because of the lower bound of integration (for radial component) which is the position of singularity, this definition is not problematic for the Kerr black hole? If yes, how?